# My Author Page goes to the second slide of my Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

I am using the following code to create a basic Beamer presentation where the first slide is the author and the institute slide and then comes the table of contents slide and then the content of the presentation (by frame) but using the code following :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{My Presentation}
\subtitle{Using Beamer}
\author{Joe Bloggs}
\institute{University of ShareLaTeX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{sub a}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The author slide is placed at the second position after the table of contents slide. Why ?

Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You had put `titlepage` after `tableofcontents`. That should make it obvious to you.

Comment: Alright thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @SolidMark It would be nice if you could post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that you placed `\titlepage` in the second `frame` environment. Since the macro  `\titlepage` generates the title slide containing author and institute, the title slide is therefore placed at the second position in your set-up.

Just change your code, so that the `frame` with `\titlepage` comes first:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\title{My Presentation}
\subtitle{Using Beamer}
\author{Joe Bloggs}
\institute{University of ShareLaTeX}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Title}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{sub a}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Result of the above code:

[image]